# Restrict Highchart draggable points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Have implemented the draggable plugin of highchart but I had a specific requirement wherein the user is allowed to drag and drop on the newly added point

```
 var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
 y = e.yAxis[0].value,
 series = this.series[seriesType];
 //tried this to set only this point as draggable
 series.draggableX  = true;
 series.draggableY  = true ;
 series.addPoint([x, y]);
```

can I set the  draggableX,draggableY to true only for this point?

Comment: Are you adding a new point, and then allowing the user to only drag that new point?  So, the last data point in the series should be draggable, but no others or should any added points should be draggable?

Comment: Suppose I have 2 points on the graph from the load those two points should not be draggable any other points that I add to the graph after that should be draggable

Answer (score 0):

I added this parameter into code, but you need to edit source.

```
function mouseDown(e) {

        var options,
            originalEvent = e.originalEvent || e,
            pointDraggableX,
            pointDraggableY,
            hoverPoint,
            series;

        if ((originalEvent.target.getAttribute('class') || '').indexOf('highcharts-handle') !== -1) {
            hoverPoint = originalEvent.target.point;
        }


        series = chart.hoverPoint && chart.hoverPoint.series;
        if (!hoverPoint && chart.hoverPoint && (!series.useDragHandle || !series.useDragHandle())) {
            hoverPoint = chart.hoverPoint;
        }

        if (hoverPoint) {
            options = hoverPoint.series.options;


            pointDraggableX = hoverPoint.draggableX !== UNDEFINED ? hoverPoint.draggableX : options.draggableX;
            pointDraggableY = hoverPoint.draggableY !== UNDEFINED ? hoverPoint.draggableY : options.draggableY;


            if (options.draggableX && pointDraggableX) {
                dragPoint = hoverPoint;
                dragX = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
                dragPlotX = dragPoint.plotX;
            }

            if (options.draggableY && pointDraggableY) {
                dragPoint = hoverPoint;

                dragY = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
                dragPlotY = dragPoint.plotY + (chart.plotHeight - (dragPoint.yBottom || chart.plotHeight));
            }

            // Disable zooming when dragging
            if (dragPoint) {
                chart.mouseIsDown = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/2607/